# Android finish parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 different activities in a `TabGroupActivity`. Let's say `A - Parent, B - Child 1, C - Child 2`.

A --- starts --> B
B --- starts --> C

and I have an alert dialog in C which shows some message. I want to go back to activity A when I press Ok button on dialog.

But the problem is that I can open activity C from other activities too and I want to go back to their parent activities too. So I need to make something which will work no matter which activity opens `C`. I've tries with this one but didn't work :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Synchronization.this,Synchronization.this.getParent().getClass());
```

but it didn't help me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You just have to make use of two [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) methods viz. [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Example : http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#explicitintents

Here goes the logic :

In ActivityB

Start ActivityC by using startActivityForResult(activityCIntent,INT_CODE);

In ActivityC

Now check if `Dialog`'s OK `Button` is pressed, if yes then set the result using `setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);` and then call `finish();`

Then control will be redirected to ActivityB's `onActivityResult()` method.
Now inside onActivityMethod() check whether `result_code==RESULT_OK` and `requestCode = INT_CODE`. If yes then simply call `finish();`

Comment: what is the difference between both the methods?

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` is used to start any other Explicit Intent and receive the results from the `Intent` that it started. `onActivityResult()` is responsible for getting the data from the started Explicit `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity B start the C Activity as `startActivityForResult()` so when you finish the C activity it will back to the B with result. As the result you may pass flag with the intent object.

Now when you finish the C activity with ok button then set the result as RESULT_OK into the setResult() if you need to pass the data back to the B activity you may set the data into the Intent add this intent with the setResult() method and then finish the C Activity.

Now in B check the requestcode is from the C then finish this Activity. As you start this C Activity you can also start the B Activity for the A Activity.

And you need to override onActivityResult() in B activity and if you start the B Activity as for result then also you need to define also into A Activity